# Exclude specific tag from selection in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I know this is a simple question, but I can't figure it out.
Consider the following simple XML document:

```
<root>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
  <a></a>
  <d></d>
  <e></e>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</root>
```

What's the best way to select the nodes `<b>` through `<e>` using XPath?

I'm looking for something like

```
/root/*[not(a)]
```

(which does not do the trick)

Comment: how about exclude more than one element? I have found out, its using select="*[not(self::abc)][not(self::def)]"

Comment: this also should work to exclude more than one element [not (abc or def)]

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
/root/*[not(self::a)]
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the main question. works for specific element and not multiple elements

Comment: @RadicalEdward The main question is, and I quote *"What's the best way to select the nodes `<b>` through `<e>` using XPath?"*. This answer does exactly that.

Comment: Main heading `Exclude certain elements from selection in XPath` . 
Disappointing that this question is not answered on the entire page.
Google Search show result for this heading `Exclude certain elements from selection in XPath` and no one that you mentioned. Though I understand answer is given according to the question asked user. Please answer to main question as well. I would appreciate.

Comment: @RadicalEdward I have *quoted* the OP's main question from the OP's post. It's their own words. This answer solves exactly what they were looking for. I suggest that you read the question again, and that you stop making assumptions from the question title alone. Your comment is unrelated to the problem discussed in this thread. Maybe that's why your idea of the question is not answered on the entire page.

Answer (score 16):

Answering to add that in XPath 2.0, you can use `except`:

```
/root/(* except a)
```

For XPath 1.0, Tomalak pointed out, this is the standard way to do it:

```
/root/*[not(self::a)]
```

By the way, if someone lands here trying to use this in XSLT 2.0 in a `xsl:template/@match` attribute it won't work because `@match` takes patterns which although *look* like XPath expressions, are *not* XPath expressions. The solution for XPath 1.0 would work in this case.

Comment: Doesn't answer the main question. works for specific element and not multiple elements

Comment: @RadicalEdward Please stop harrassing everybody in an almost 8 year old thread just because you misunderstood the problem that was asked.

Answer (score 10):

I realize this is an old question, but I recently ran into a similar problem and used the following xpath to solve it:

```
/root/*[not(name()='a')]
```

Answer (score -5):

Have you tried:

/root/b|/root/c|root/d|/root/e

Comment: That's how I had it implemented. Unfortunately, there might be other nodes with unknown names

Comment: Doesn't answer the main question. works for specific element and not multiple elements