# How to select node's text which isn't script with xpath in python3'lxml.html?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml.html

Environment:python3+lxml.
Here is a test.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>it is a test for xpath</p>
    <a>it is a test for xpath</a>
    <script>$(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "/account/getUserInfo",
            async:false,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) {  }
            }
    })
});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To extract all the texts in all nodes in test.html.

```
import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.parse("test.html")
texts = tree.xpath('//*/text()')
for text in texts:
    print(text)
```

With the xpath expression, **tree.xpath('//*/text()')**,all the text belong to html tags output as below.

```
Document
it is a test for xpath
it is a test for xpath
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "/account/getUserInfo",
            async:false,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) {  }
            }
    })
});
```

To extract scripts' text with xpath  texts = tree.xpath('//script/text()').
Now i want to extract all node's text except script's.

```
xpath("*[name(.) !='script']/text()")
xpath('*[not(script)]/text()']
xpath('node(not(script))/text()')
```

None of them can do,how to fix it?

Comment: Similar question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068636/exclude-certain-elements-from-selection-in-xpath

Comment: `tree.xpath('/body/(* except script)/text()')` can't do.

Comment: `texts = tree.xpath('//body/*[not(self::script)]/text()')` can output part of it.

Comment: ` texts = tree.xpath('//*[not(self::script)]/text()')`  can  match all of the texts in nodes except script.